# How to ask forgiveness for immaturity?

Tags: allah

It was the year 2011 and i was around 10-11 years old at that time. I used to watch a show and i liked the hero a lot. I kinda had a crush on him. But he got into a relationship and married her which i didn’t like. So i made dua to break his marriage which i didn't like.But after being married for 7 years they got a divorce. Although i stopped making for breaking their relationship after their marriage was my dua responsible for their divorce?  I wanted to break their affair but not their marriage. Am i responsible?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be sure in sensitive situations if a person is responsible. The best is to ask for forgiveness in any case even if there is slight doubt. And move on, the best we can do is ask for forgiveness for past affairs.